# Invalid logback pattern

Tags: java, logging, logback

I was using this working pattern (logback.groovy):

```
{'((?:password(=|:|>))|(?:secret(=|:))|(?:salt(=|:)))','\$1*******\$3'}
```

to mask sensitive data. One day I needed to surround it with double quotes, like

was: `password=smth`
became: `"password"="smth"`

So I turned regexp into this (just added `\"` before and after keywords, and also I've tried `\\"`):

`{'(\"?(?:password\"?(=|:|>))|(?:secret\"?(=|:))|(?:salt\"?(=|:)))','\$1*******\$3'}`

But I get this error on app startup:

> Failed to parse pattern
> Unexpected character ('?' (code 63)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries

Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone wondering here is correct version:

```
{'(\\\"?(?:password\\\"?(=|:|>))|(?:secret\\\"?(=|:))|(?:salt\\\"?(=|:)))','\$1*******\$3'}
```